# Как определить расширения файла на c++?

Tags: c++

Как определить расширения файла на c++?

Answer (score 5):

Например, так

```
string get_ext (const string& st) {
    size_t pos = st.rfind('.');
    if (pos <= 0) return "";
    return st.substr(pos+1, string::npos);
}
```

Или в случае нахождения файла в сети

```
string get_net_ext (const string& st) {
    size_t pos = st.find_last_of ("./");
    if (pos <=0 || st[pos] =='/') return "";
    return st.substr(pos+1, string::npos);
}
```

Comment: А если расширения файла скрыта через .htaccess?

Просто я открываю файл который лежит не у меня на диске, а на сайте

Comment: Уточните вопрос.

Comment: Я не очень спец в сетевом программировании, но что-то смутно вспоминая как я однажды настраивал аппач, думаю, что никак ))) Если сокрыто, то сокрыто. Хотя, может, более знающие укажут способ.

Comment: @fast, с одной стороны, какая задача, такой ответ, а с другой, @mikillskegg мог бы это учесть и написать что-то поинтереснее=)